# How to access captured data from Event Hub in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 using Python

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub, azure-sdk-python

I'm using the connection_string to access an Azure Data Lake Gen2 storage, in which lots of Avro files were stored by an Event Hubs Capture, under the typical directory structure containing folders named by year/month/day/hour/minute. I'm using the azure.storage.filedatalake package.

Firstly I get a Data Lake service client using:

`datalake_service_client = DataLakeServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)`

And then I get the file systems in the lake by:

```
file_systems = datalake_service_client.list_file_systems()
for file_system in file_systems:
    print(file_system.name)
```

There is only one file system in this case, called "datalake1". At this point I want to access to all the Avro files I expect to find therein. I'm trying by firstly getting a file system client:

file_system_client = datalake_service_client.get_file_system_client("datalake1")

and then by using the get_paths method:

`file_system_client.get_paths()`

It returns an iterator (azure.core.paging.ItemPaged object), but from here I'm not being able to see the folders and files. I tried with a simple list comprehension like `[x.name for x in file_system_client.get_paths()]` but I got the error **StorageErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status 'The specified container does not exist.'**

Any idea about how to access the Avro files following this procedure?

EDIT: I'm using azure-storage-file-datalake version 12.0.0. Here a screenshot of the code:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update:**

Tested it with your code:

[image]

---

**original answer:**

After you call `get_paths()` method, you can use `is_directory` property to determine if it's a directory or a file. If it's a file, then you can do something with it.

The sample code(in this sample, I just print out the `.avro` file path. Please feel free to modify the code to meet your need):

```
#other code
paths = file_system_client.get_paths()

for path in paths:
    #determine if it is a directory or a file
    if not path.is_directory:
        #here, just print out the file name.
        print(path.name + '\n')
        #you can do other operations here.
```

The test result:

[image]

Comment: I do this but still get the same error. I guess eh1 in your case is the name of the container, right? In my case it's datalake1, I get this name by doing `file_systems = datalake_service_client.list_file_systems()` and then `for file_system in file_systems: print(file_system.name)`. The error above indicates **The specified container does not exist**, but if I run `container = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, container_name="datalake1")` and then `container.list_blobs()`, I manage to list the name of all blobs without problems. How is possible?

Comment: @datariel, yes, the `eh1` is the container name. And how many containers(file system) in your account? I will give it a try later.

Comment: @datariel, can you just post the completed code in your question? I did a quick test, no error occurs, everything is fine. And also let me know which version of `azure-storage-file-datalake` you are using(I'm using the latest one, 12.0.0).

Comment: yes, I'm using `azure-storage-file-datalake` version 12.0.0, too. I added the full code to the edited question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @datariel, I tested it with your code, and no error. Can you create a new `Data Lake Storage Gen2`, then run the code again? It may be some thing related to `the current ADLS Gen2`

Comment: thank you for confirming this. Yes, I'll create a new Data Lake and retry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the connection string. I tried again but taking it from the "Access keys" blade in the Azure portal, and now it's working fine. I managed to run correctly get_paths() and more. The previous connection string was taken from the Storage Explorer, which corresponds to the connection string retrieved from the "Shared access signature" blade. Credits to @MartinJaffer-MSFT ([MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df9035a3-cbd8-4cd0-a390-1bf9ba61af15/how-to-access-captured-data-from-event-hub-in-azure-data-lake-storage-gen2-using-python?forum=AzureDataLake)).